# how to click on specific result on google with Selenium?

Tags: java, selenium, automation, ui-automation

For the example, I'm navigating to https://google.com, then search for `"Facebook"`.

the 2nd result is https://Facebook.com

the `href` is:

```
href="/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&sqi=2&ved=0ahUKEwim2e368Y_SAhVHDcAKHXKfD0wQFgglMAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.facebook.com%2F&usg=AFQjCNGug_CqO9cxLI8dHdn-CceO8_ie5w&sig2=8e9cdct3GrJ8ZqdUiPsXCQ&bvm=bv.146786187,d.bGg"
```

I also get:

```
data-href="https://www.facebook.com/"
```

how can I find the element with this data?

Answer (score 1):

You can find required link `By.cssSelector("a[data-href='https://www.facebook.com/']")`

or using `XPath`- `By.xpath("//a[@data-href='https://www.facebook.com/']")`

Comment: Do you get any exception? Show code you use to handle link

Answer (score 0):

Don't evaluate data-href it is added dynamicly to the element only after a onmousedown event. You probably used the "inspect element" feature which triggers the event. Use ctrl-shift C instead to inspect elements.

You can simply click on : "//a[@href='https://www.facebook.com/']"